# Android Relative Layout image overlay

Tags: android, image, imageview, android-relativelayout

[image]

Well I have 2 images and I want show like this. second image should be right corner of first image. bottom or top is not important.

I am trying with relative layout but not looking like this

I want to put cancel image to the bottom of image first with this

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

but it goes the screen bottom not image bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use Frame Layout for this purpose  beause frame layout does not require any relationships, like  with `android:layout_gravity="top|right"` property as :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image1"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top|right"

        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
    </ImageView>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dip"
        android:layout_below="@id/image1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
    </ImageView>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: well it is working but there is yellow alert on:Invalid layout param in a FrameLayout: layout_below

Answer (score 0):

AlignParentBottom will only set the image to the bottom of the page, what you need is to align the image below the (X) image, and the (X) image be aligned right in the parent. Just change the src of the code pasted below and see if it wor

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image1"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
        </ImageView>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/image1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
        </ImageView>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Used below code it definitely help you.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<FrameLayout   
    android:layout_width="210dp"
    android:layout_height="210dp"
    >

    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="190dp"
            android:layout_height="180dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="@drawable/red_button"
           >
    </ImageView>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image1"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:background="@drawable/icon" >
        </ImageView>
    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks

Comment: There has 
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup 

PLease check \

Answer (score 0):

make an Activity with Transparent theme in manifest like this:

```
<activity android:name=".MyDialogActivity" android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" />
```

and then define layout like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <RelativeLayout android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_margin="15dp" android:padding="2dp">
        <!-- Contents will go here..-->
    </RelativeLayout>
    <Button android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:text="X"
        android:textColor="#FFF" android:background="@drawable/round_button_background"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="5dp" android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_width="25dp" android:textSize="12sp" android:textStyle="bold"
        android:onClick="cancelActivity" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and define a background for your close Button in drawable like this:

round_button_background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="#9F2200" />
    <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#FFF" />
</shape>
```